# SharePoint 2013 List Last Modified/Created PowerShell

Tags: arrays, list, powershell, sharepoint-2013

I am able to access a SharePoint site using PowerShell and printing items in a list sub folder. However, I would like to copy the item with the last modified date to the local server. How can I get the last modified. The items do not have a lastwritetime method that I can use.

Comment: [This implies they have a ModifiedDate](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70236/delete-list-items-using-powershells-with-date-filtering) property

Comment: I was looking at the example. They do have a modified date but I am not sure how I can grab the latest modified version of the items in the list and download it. I was hoping there was a min/max property for the date and I could not find a command for downloading an item form a list.